# Validation Error OraOLEDB.Oracle.1 is not registered

Tags: windows, oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I am using **Visual Studio 2015** for developing SSIS packages and I have a 64-bit pc windows OS.

I have a *Connection Manager* with Connection String property set as:

```
Data Source=TEST;User ID=test;Password=test123;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=True;
```

The Provider is OraOleDB.Oracle.1 as you can see.

On opening the package in Visual Studio, I get this error:

*Validation Error...The requested OLE DB provider OraOLE.DB.Oracle.1 is not registered. If the 32-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 64-bit mode...Description:"Class not registered".*

To solve this issue, I tried a few steps I read online:

1. Installed Oracle 64 bit Client
2. I believe this client has the Oracle Driver (64 bit) with it. I checked the provider is present by creating a dummy file test.udl. Right click on the file > properties > provider and I see there is **Oracle Provider for OLE DB** present.
3. ORACLE_HOME is set, TNS_ADMIN is set, PATH pointing to /bin all set up and tnsnames.ora file is also present under /network/admin.
4. Attempted to set property Run64BitRuntime to TRUE and FALSE
5. registered the .dll file using regsvr32.exe.

Despite all these steps above, I am still receiving the error. When I open the package the connection manager goes into work offline mode. My question is, How do I do know which mode package is running on. is there any missing components I need to look for?

Comment: No Oracle Client (at least the Oracle Instant Client) does not include OLE DB Provider. You have to download and install separately: [Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) for Windows Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html)